# Best practices to share common types among layers

Tags: .net, oop, architecture

I have a Business Layer which has some common types to transfer data to Service Layer (which is fine so far), but, I also have a Presentation Layer that needs to access the common type in BL, I don't want to expose BL classes to PL.

I was thinking of creating a shared library in BL and make it accessible to all layers OR create new classes in SL and inherit them from BL classes.

What is the best way to approach this problem.
My SL is a WCF project and will be hosted as a service. PL is mostly Web Forms and MVC.

Comment: Create a shared library to share common types between other assemblies/libraries?  Sounds good to me :)

Comment: True, but I would end up with a library with a lot of unrelated classes and enums, is that gonna be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ancient question of how far up the stack to share the business
>   objects.

You want to have a service layer, but you don't want to map objects over and over again -> well this signals multiple things:

1. you probably see that all those objects will be 1:1 (hence the question). If this is true, then you are building a very simple application, and you can avoid this by either not having the service layer at all, or by having business objects shared all the way to the UI (highest coupling by far, but could work if you control both side of client and server, application is very CRUD-only, and there is only one client application)
2. if it is anything more complex, especially with multiple clients, separate the service layer objects from business objects completely (and don't inherit them, if you do that then you could simply expose the business objects as well - hardly any difference). In case the UI is simple enough, you could "use" the objects that service layer returns. Otherwise, split the presentation objects to own objects as well (view models, presentation models or any other pattern).

Having three "layers" of objects sound more complex than really is, many tools can help with this (AutoMapper for example), but normally the complexity comes when application is in nature simple but still has many such layers; otherwise you clearly see the benefits.

Btw, I simplified the problem quite a lot, and the whole talk is about "sharing objects". In reality there are many other things that could come into play, and simplify things or change the context completely (OData service for example, or having dynamically typed language on the client etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, I guess I will go with a shared dll since there is a 1:1 object mapping and we control both client and server.

Comment: Just keep in mind the realistic middle-long term vision for the project as well